# ls command lists hidden files

Tags: ubuntu, ls

When I run `ls` command I get files like `opencv.sh~` in my output which is not visible if I check the home directory.

Basically, it also lists hidden files without supplying any other parameter. How can I prevent this ?

My dist is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opencv.sh~` is not a hidden file. POSIX defines a hidden file as one starting with a dot, but `opencv.sh~` does not start with a dot.

If you don't want to see these files, you can explicitly avoid them by using a glob that doesn't include them (for example, `shopt -s extglob` followed by `ls !(*\~)`), or (as I assume these are from vim), you can [configure vim not to put backup files in the same directory](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory).

Comment: You're correct. Then how can I prevent ls from listing files like that? Is it possible ?

Comment: But still, that opencv.sh~ is not visible when I check the home directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "is not visible"? If your file manager hides that from you, that's file manager specific logic.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. So, can I configure ls so that it lists only what file manager shows ?

Comment: @SpiderRico That would require you to know what your file manager does and does not show :-) I've shown how to exclude this specific example in the answer -- you can customise this appropriately and make it into an alias if desired.

Comment: Rite I see the logic behind it ty. So, everything is fine with ls command I assume. These files are probably from atom btw.

Answer (score 3):

There's no property on a file that indicates that it's hidden. Early versions of Unix had an `ls` command that [hid files whose name begins with `.` (“dot files”)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) and that tradition stuck. The `ls` command, by default, hides files whose name begins with `.` and shows all other files.

Some graphical file managers hide files whose name begins with `.`, just like `ls`, because that's what many users expect. [Gnome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#GNOME) has launched a new convention, which is that directories can contain a file called `.hidden` which contains a list of files to hide (one file name per line, no patterns allowed).

You didn't mention which file manager you used, it's possible that it has different rules for hiding files. If `opencv.sh~` is hidden, that follows decidedly non-standard rules, so you can't legitimately complain that `ls` isn't following these non-standard rules.

Adding a `~` at the end of a file name is the convention for a backup file. That is, `opencv.sh~` is an earlier version of `opencv.sh`, created by your editor when you saved `opencv.sh`.

The GNU version of `ls` supports an option `-I` to ignore extra patterns (in addition to dot files). If you want to hide backup files from `ls`, you can make an alias that adds `-I "*~"` to the `ls` options:

```
alias ls='ls -I "*~"'
```

(plus any other option you wish, e.g. `alias ls='ls -I "*~"' --color` to use colors to indicate file types). Put that line in your `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` or whatever initialization file your shell uses.